# C# no data returned from database - "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present"

Tags: c#, sql

I am try to display data from a database. However even though data exists in the database no records are being returned.

If run the following query:

```
select Id, Movie_Name from [MovieTable] where Movie_Name like '10,000 BC'
```

I get being returned:

[image]

However when running a similar query in c# nothing seems to be being returned. My code is as follows:

```
try
{
    string query = "select * from [MovieTable] where Movie_Name like @MovieName";
    string movieName = "10,000 BC"

    using (SqlConnection sconnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=E:\Application\ApplicationDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");)
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, sconnection))
    {
        sconnection.Open();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovieName", movieName);

        using (SqlDataReader oReader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (oReader != null)
            {
                while (oReader.Read())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(oReader["Movie_Name"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

The message box never appears. Adding a third message box just above oReader.Read() displays the message "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present". Is there something i am missing?

Comment: that message is beause you cant ask for data from a datareader before you have it read the data.  MessageBox is a horrible way to debug code

Comment: This is a windows forms app right?  If you get the year value to a variable, and point a breakpoint there, what does it show?

Comment: Nothing as it doesn't seem to enter the while loop

Comment: I have to ask, what's the point in using `like` in a SQL statement if you're going to use it exactly like an equals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the data itself. Field was incorrectly set as type "Text". I altered the fields data type to "nvarchar(MAX)". It also mean't the query could be altered to:

```
"select * from [MovieTable] where Movie_Name = @MovieName"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs fine for me, with little adaptions though.
You query the value of the attribute 'Year' which is not present in the table and in your first query:

```
oReader.GetOrdinal("Year")
```

That causes an exception in the sample.

Single Quotes are not needed since you are using a parametrized query.
For debugging calls to System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine() are more useful than MessageBoxes